# Convergence of sums of complex exponentials

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, complex-numbers

Suppose you have the following sum
\begin{align}
    s_n := \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} a_j e^{-i \omega j}
\end{align}
where $\omega$ is some real number and $i^2 = -1$. If you knew that $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} a_j \rightarrow \bar{a} < \infty$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$,

1. Could you say that $s_n \rightarrow \bar{s} < \infty$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$?
2. If so, what is $\bar{s}$? My guess would be something like $\bar{s} = \int_0^1 \bar{a} e^{-i\omega s} ds$ because $\bar{a} = \int_0^1 \bar{a} ds$, you get the weighted sum of exponential functions in there and it looks an awful lot like a Riemann sum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no without some regularity conditions on $a_j$ as the simple example $a_{2k}=1, a_{2k+1}=-1, \omega =\pi, \bar a=0$ but $s_n=1$ shows that the limit may exist but not be the integral

If one instead uses $a_{2k}=k/\log (k+1), a_{2k+1}=-k/\log (k+1), \omega =\pi, \bar a=0$, but $s_n \to \infty$, so the limit also may not exist in the sense of being infinite

With a bit more care, one can get oscillating $s_n$ etc

Comment: If we have the stronger conditions that $a_j \rightarrow \bar{a}$?

Comment: then $s_n \to 0$ if $\omega \ne 2k\pi$ and to $\bar a$ if $\omega =2k\pi$ as in the first case the partial sums of the exponential terms are uniformly bounded, so using summation by parts the result follows easily (since if we consider $t_n$ the sum where we replace $a_j$ by $\bar a$ so in other words just the average of the exponentials multiplied by $\bar a$ we easily get that $s_n-t_n \to 0$)

Comment: note also that $s_n$is not Riemann sum from $[0,1]$ (essentially it is one from $[0,\infty)$ but of an oscillating function so we cannot really say much about it apriori); it would be such if the terms were $e^{-i \omega j/n}$